# Is it possible to insert X-Frame-Options into every HTTP response?

Tags: security, http-headers

X-Frame-Options HTTP header field is used  for prevention against clickjacking attacks. Is it possible to insert X-Frame-Options into every HTTP response?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question. Your question does not provide any information regarding your context, e.g. what server are you talking about? Also provide some code or configuration of what you have tried.

Comment: Apologize for not being clear. I am referring to the feature "HTTP Header Field X-Frame-Options" [https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7034] for header security where x-frame-options is used to prevent clickjacking attacks. I would like to know if this header is inserted in every http response generated by the server to the client.

Comment: what server? it depends on implementation and configuration

Answer (score 0):

for Apache web server use mod_headers :

- [Apache mod_headers](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_headers.html)

and add "Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN".

There are three settings for X-Frame-Options:

- SAMEORIGIN: This setting will allow page to be displayed in frame on the same origin as the page itself.
- DENY: This setting will prevent a page displaying in a frame or iframe.
- ALLOW-FROM uri: This setting will allow page to be displayed only on the specified origin.